# Why do some processors implement a separate address space for IO devices?

Tags: io, x86, address-space, cpu-architecture

I'm wondering what the exact reason was to implement a separate address space and instruction set for IO devices, especially the x86 architecture.

*Linux Device Drivers* [[Chp. 9]](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-1) remains stating some manufacturers "decided that peripheral devices are different from memory and, therefore, deserve a separate address space". 
What aspect is meant by this, can someone clarify and give background?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O

Comment: well, this explains why port-mapped IO became obsolete but why where extra instructions implemented like `in` and `out` if the memory instructions could be used to access it?

Comment: @e1kable Now it's just for the sake of compatibility. What was the primary motivation for the original design is moslty a historical question. Maybe the lack of free address space, or an attempt to protect I/O ports etc.

Comment: @e1kable Port-mapped I/O is not really obsolete. It is still used to program external controllers. There are many slow and/or rare operations out of there. Only fast I/O operations need direct memory access.